# Android CDT setup std cannot be resolved

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

I have been programing with the CDT for a while, and it has worked fine.  In general everything works with it, for example I can import opencv fine by typing

```
using namespace cv;
```

However, right now there are two imports that don't work, that I need.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

These both are underlined, the std causing a compile error(the other just a warning).  When I set it up, [this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#building-application-native-part-from-eclipse-cdt-builder) told me that the following includes will take those errors away:

```
# for NDK r8b and later:
${NDKROOT}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
${ProjDirPath}/../../sdk/native/jni/include
```

However that only helped for the opencv stuff.  I am using NDK v r8d(most recent to my knowledge).  Other than these includes, I can get it to compile and build.  I would appreciate any pointer in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this isnt anywhere in the OpenCV Docs, but heres how you get it to compile:

In addition to the includes above, you need to also include two more(if there not already there).  You need to find where your c++ files are. On a mac, they will be at /usr/include.  So add the following two imports under **Project Properties->C/C++ General-> Paths and Symbols->Includes Tab**

```
/usr/include/c++/<your version of c++>
/usr/include
```

In my case the above was like this:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
/usr/include
```

Comment: didn't change anything for me

Comment: @austin , Was this definitely the same issue for you? I had a few issues before I got to this one

Comment: i can see this was a not the same issue now that i've learned more about it

Comment: This actually helpe me with #include <vector> and using namespace std after which the program run. I still have #include <jni.h> with a yellow marker but since it is part of ndk and for some reason it cannot be found (Cannot run program "/ndk-build.cmd": Unknown reason) I just run it on src manually. There should be  a "proper" way to do this though...